# Unable to access Google buckets using spark-submit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-storage, spark-submit

I'm trying to access google buckets, when using spark-submit and running into issues.

Here is the command, and the error :

```
Command :
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.0 --jars gs://spark-jars-karan/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.23.2.jar,gs://spark-jars-karan/spark-avro_2.12-3.1.2.jar  /Users/karanalang/PycharmProjects/Kafka/StructuredStreaming_GCP_Versa_Sase.py

Error :
22/02/11 20:06:59 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "gs"
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3443)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.spark.util.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPath(DependencyUtils.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.util.DependencyUtils$.$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2(DependencyUtils.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.util.DependencyUtils$.$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2$adapted(DependencyUtils.scala:271)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:293)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:293)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:290)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPaths(DependencyUtils.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$4(SparkSubmit.scala:364)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Tried this modified query(adding --conf spark.hadoop.fs.gs.impl=com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem)aand getting ClassNotFoundError :

```
Modified command :

spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.0 --conf spark.hadoop.fs.gs.impl=com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem --jars gs://spark-jars-karan/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.23.2.jar,gs://spark-jars-karan/spark-avro_2.12-3.1.2.jar  /Users/karanalang/PycharmProjects/Kafka/StructuredStreaming_GCP_Versa_Sase.py

Error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.spark.util.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPath(DependencyUtils.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.util.DependencyUtils$.$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2(DependencyUtils.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.util.DependencyUtils$.$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2$adapted(DependencyUtils.scala:271)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:293)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:293)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:290)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPaths(DependencyUtils.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$4(SparkSubmit.scala:364)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2665)
```

What needs to be done to debug/fix this ?
tia!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a Google storage bucket gs:// from your local host.

It does not see it because spark-submit assumes that it is a local file system on the host which is not.

You need to mount gs:// bucket as a local file system.

You can use the tool called gcsfuse https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse . Cloud Storage FUSE is an open source FUSE adapter that allows you to mount Cloud Storage buckets as file systems on Linux or macOS systems. You can download gcsfuse from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse

Pretty simple.

It will be installed as /usr/bin/gcsfuse and you can mount it by creating a local mount file like /mnt/gs as root and give permission to others to use it.

As a normal user that needs to access gs:// bucket (not as root), use gcsfuse to mount it. For example I am mounting a gcs bucket called spark-jars-karan here

Just use the bucket name itself

```
gcsfuse spark-jars-karan /mnt/gs
```

Then you can refer to it as /mnt/gs in spark-submit from on-premise host

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.0 --jars /mnt/gs/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.23.2.jar
```

Comment: thnx, will check and update